# How to use different font from Google Fonts on "Headings" of bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass

I change de font family of the entire bootstrap using a custom.SCSS file with the following code:

```
      //Import Fonts
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
    
    $font-family-sans-serif: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !default;
    
    $headings-font-family: inherit;
    $headings-font-weight: 900;
    
    // Override default variables before the import
    $body-bg: #ffff;

    // Import Bootstrap and its default variables
    @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

but I dont find which SCSS variable I have to overwrite , I Just want to change the font style and family of all the headings on Bootstrap, but not to change de

or others.

Answer (score 1):

Your code says `$headings-font-family: inherit;` which means that the heading will use whatever font the container where it is inside uses.

If you want your headings to use a different font than you have to declare this in the `$headings-font-family` variable.

```css
$headings-font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
```

This will result in the headings using the fonts defined by `$font-family-sans-serif`.

### Edit

You should first include Bootsrap and then add your modifications, otherwise they might get overwritten!

Comment: You should *first* declare your variables, and *then* load Boostrap - because Bootstrap internally declares *default* values for variables, which means if something else was already declared (by you) for that variable by the time Bootstrap is loaded, then your declaration is favored over the internal default value.